# AudioCookBook: pesky problem: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format) error in IOS simulator

Tags: audiokit

Apologies for the 'almost' duplicate question.  AudioCookBook sample app crashes in my IOS simulator when I choose Channel/Device routing. The error is 'IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format).  Here is the entire log. Please help

Adding more info. Below is the code related to crash and the crash log

```
Error shows up here:

 private func createEngineMixer() {
        guard mainMixerNode == nil else { return }

        let mixer = Mixer(name: "AudioKit Engine Mixer")
        avEngine.attach(mixer.avAudioNode)
        avEngine.connect(mixer.avAudioNode, to: avEngine.outputNode, format: Settings.audioFormat) <------ crash is from here
        mainMixerNode = mixer 
    }

---- log ---------
0 18:30:45.519218-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000031e15a0> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46
2022-02-20 18:30:45.520038-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322]  AudioObjectSetPropertyData: no object with given ID 0
2022-02-20 18:30:45.520222-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] AudioSessionSimulatorClientManager.cpp:83    Failed to set processVolumeScalar on device. Error: 560947818
2022-02-20 18:30:45.652544-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [UIFocus] Focus system enabled
2022-02-20 18:30:48.166409-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [general] AVAudioFile+Utilities.swift:toAVAudioPCMBuffer():39:Created buffer with format <AVAudioFormat 0x6000012ee260:  2 ch,  44100 Hz, Float32, non-inter> (AVAudioFile+Utilities.swift:toAVAudioPCMBuffer():39)

2022-02-20 18:30:48.781631-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] throwing -10878
2022-02-20 18:30:48.787880-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:878   couldn't get default output device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2022-02-20 18:30:48.788269-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527] [ddagg]        AggregateDevice.mm:878   couldn't get default input device, ID = 0, err = 0!
2022-02-20 18:30:48.788446-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2022-02-20 18:30:48.788680-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:48.788809-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved>)
2022-02-20 18:30:48.788839-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:48.789037-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519]      CA_UISoundClient.cpp:123   * * * NULL AQIONode object
2022-02-20 18:30:48.789281-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519]      CA_UISoundClient.cpp:880   Can't make UISound Renderer
2022-02-20 18:30:48.809033-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2022-02-20 18:30:48.809312-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171527] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:48.809461-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 2, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved>)

2022-02-20 18:30:58.880400-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171673]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2022-02-20 18:30:58.880765-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171673] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:58.881015-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved>)
2022-02-20 18:30:58.882141-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171673]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2022-02-20 18:30:58.882738-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171673] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:58.882903-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 1, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved>)
2022-02-20 18:30:58.883414-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] throwing -10878


2022-02-20 18:30:58.934781-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:58.934920-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519]  AudioDeviceStop: no device with given ID
2022-02-20 18:30:58.935184-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171519] [aqme]                AQMEIO.cpp:377   error -66680 finding/initializing Default-InputOutput
2022-02-20 18:30:58.935341-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [aurioc]            AURemoteIO.cpp:1128  failed: -10851 (enable 3, outf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved> inf< 2 ch,      0 Hz, Int16, interleaved>)
2022-02-20 18:30:58.935824-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] [avae]            AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:2128:_Connect: (IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format))]
2022-02-20 18:30:59.019001-0800 Cookbook[2216:8171322] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203feba4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff201a1be7 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203fe9cd +[NSException raise:format:] + 0
    3   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff5a59254e _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 156
    4   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff5a5dd543 _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph8_ConnectEP19AVAudioNodeImplBaseS1_jjP13AVAudioFormat + 323
    5   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff5a5e4cf8 _ZN18AVAudioEngineGraph7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 586
    6   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff5a65b37f _ZN17AVAudioEngineImpl7ConnectEP11AVAudioNodeS1_mmP13AVAudioFormat + 1041
    7   AVFAudio                            0x00007fff5a655ae0 -[AVAudioEngine connect:to:format:] + 114
    8   Cookbook                            0x000000010b4c28ac $s8AudioKit0A6EngineC06createC5Mixer33_BBA7C59B6014A6A2181272B002E0697ELLyyF + 524
    9   Cookbook                            0x000000010b4c227a $s8AudioKit0A6EngineC6outputAA4Node_pSgvW + 1770
    10  Cookbook                            0x000000010b4c2559 $s8AudioKit0A6EngineC6outputAA4Node_pSgvs + 233
    11  Cookbook                            0x000000010b37277b $s8Cookbook29ChannelDeviceRoutingConductorCACycfc + 1499
    12  Cookbook                            0x000000010b372191 $s8Cookbook29ChannelDeviceRoutingConductorCACycfC + 33
    13  Cookbook                            0x000000010b373898 $s8Cookbook24ChannelDeviceRoutingViewV10_conductor33_AF54AAB306277EF7AAE12FA1F3DA8269LL7SwiftUI11StateObjectVyAA0bcD9ConductorCGvpfiAJycfu_AJycfu0_ + 24
    14  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cbc26f2 $s7SwiftUI11StateObjectV3Box33_26399901AD247149EF526863F9AAF7C4LLV6update8property5phaseSbACyxGz_AA12_GraphInputsV5PhaseVtF + 74
    15  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d177bb5 $s7SwiftUI9BoxVTable33_68550FF604D39F05971FE35A26EE75B0LLC6update3ptr8property5phaseSbSv_SvAA12_GraphInputsV5PhaseVtFZ + 207
    16  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d176fe4 $s7SwiftUI22_DynamicPropertyBufferV6update9container5phaseSbSv_AA12_GraphInputsV5PhaseVtF + 72
    17  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5da31 $s7SwiftUI11DynamicBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyF + 296
    18  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    19  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    20  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    21  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    22  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    23  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d5b1 $s7SwiftUI10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV9container9ContainerQzvg + 67
    24  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d675 $s7SwiftUI10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyF + 142
    25  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    26  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    27  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    28  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    29  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    30  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c761be4 $s7SwiftUI26MakeResolvedRepresentation33_AC03956538119E2820390436C305EBF1LLV5value4BodyQzvgAA0D11ButtonStyleV_Tg5 + 30
    31  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c7eab41 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA4RuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_7SwiftUI19ResolvedButtonStyleV4bodyQrvpQOy_Qo__AK04MakeH14Representation33_AC03956538119E2820390436C305EBF1LLVyAMGTg5 + 37
    32  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    33  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    34  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    35  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    36  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c79b315 $s7SwiftUI10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyFAA04ViewD8AccessorVyAA6ButtonVyAA09PrimitiveR18StyleConfigurationV5LabelVGG_AA15MainThreadFlagsACLLVTg5 + 64
    37  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c814510 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_7SwiftUI6ButtonV4bodyQrvpQOyAK09PrimitiveI18StyleConfigurationV5LabelV_Qo__AK10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLVyAK04ViewP8AccessorVyAMyARGGAK15MainThreadFlagsAULLVGTg5TA + 15
    38  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    39  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    40  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    41  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    42  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c7eaacb $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA4RuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_7SwiftUI15ModifiedContentVyAK19ResolvedButtonStyleVAK0kL8ModifierVyAK07DefaultkL0VGG_AK04MakeN14Representation33_AC03956538119E2820390436C305EBF1LLVyAOGTg5 + 29
    43  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    44  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    45  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    46  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    47  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d5b1 $s7SwiftUI10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV9container9ContainerQzvg + 67
    48  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d675 $s7SwiftUI10StaticBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyF + 142
    49  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    50  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    51  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    52  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    53  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    54  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d9eb $s7SwiftUI11DynamicBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyF + 226
    55  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    56  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    57  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    58  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    59  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    60  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5ce5d9eb $s7SwiftUI11DynamicBody33_49D2A32E637CD497C6DE29B8E060A506LLV11updateValueyyF + 226
    61  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    62  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    63  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    64  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554

    82  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    83  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    84  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    85  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    86  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d0bc11a $s7SwiftUI15_ViewList_GroupV4InitV5valueAA0cD0_pvg + 183
    87  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c7e717a $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA4RuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_7SwiftUI8ViewList_p_AK01_hI6_GroupV4InitVTg5 + 37
    88  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    89  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    90  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    91  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    92  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cb91711 $s7SwiftUI24DynamicLayoutViewAdaptor33_8B9C7F39264416187A895085215951BCLLV12updatedItemsAA0E4List_pSgyF + 59
    93  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c6f4d91 $s7SwiftUI20DynamicContainerInfoV11updateItems33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELL18disableTransitionsSb7changed_Sb8hasDepthtSb_tFAA0C17LayoutViewAdaptor33_8B9C7F39264416187A895085215951BCLLV_Tg5 + 53
    94  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c6f3453 $s7SwiftUI20DynamicContainerInfoV11updateValueyyFAA0C17LayoutViewAdaptor33_8B9C7F39264416187A895085215951BCLLV_Tg5 + 460
    95  SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c80a7a5 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_7SwiftUI16DynamicContainerV4InfoV_AK0ijK0VyAK0I17LayoutViewAdaptor33_8B9C7F39264416187A895085215951BCLLVGTg5TA + 15
    96  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    97  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    98  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    99  AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    100 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c961b29 $s7SwiftUI25DynamicPreferenceCombiner33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELLV4infoAA0C9ContainerV4InfoVSgvg + 62
    101 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c961cae $s7SwiftUI25DynamicPreferenceCombiner33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELLV5value5ValueQzvg + 128
    102 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c962105 $s7SwiftUI25DynamicPreferenceCombiner33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELLVyxG14AttributeGraph4RuleAafGP5value5ValueQzvgTW + 23
    103 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffbbbe7 $s14AttributeGraph4RuleP5value5ValueQzvgTj + 7
    104 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c885800 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA4RuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_ + 109
    105 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    106 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    107 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    108 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    109 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cdb0e7b $s7SwiftUI24HostPreferencesTransform33_5EC2B8E51282B711F818D51701767C64LLV11updateValueyyF + 83
    110 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    111 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    112 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    113 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    114 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    115 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cdb0e7b $s7SwiftUI24HostPreferencesTransform33_5EC2B8E51282B711F818D51701767C64LLV11updateValueyyF + 83
    116 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    117 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    118 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    119 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    120 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    121 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cdb0e7b $s7SwiftUI24HostPreferencesTransform33_5EC2B8E51282B711F818D51701767C64LLV11updateValueyyF + 83
    122 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d04f428 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA12StatefulRuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_TA + 26
    123 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    124 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    125 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1d18 _ZN2AG5Graph20input_value_ref_slowENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEENS_11AttributeIDEjPK15AGSwiftMetadataRhl + 554
    126 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb8729 AGGraphGetValue + 210
    127 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c961f49 $s7SwiftUI25DynamicPreferenceCombiner33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELLV5value5ValueQzvg + 795
    128 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c962105 $s7SwiftUI25DynamicPreferenceCombiner33_023AA827B8A8D39774F7A0C281455FEELLVyxG14AttributeGraph4RuleAafGP5value5ValueQzvgTW + 23
    129 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffbbbe7 $s14AttributeGraph4RuleP5value5ValueQzvgTj + 7
    130 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c885800 $s14AttributeGraph0A0VyACyxGqd__c5ValueQyd__RszAA4RuleRd__lufcADSPyqd__GXEfU_ySv_So11AGAttributeatcyXEfU_ySv_AJtcqd__mcfu_ySv_AJtcfu0_ + 109
    131 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b37b _ZN2AG5Graph11UpdateStack6updateEv + 553
    132 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ff9b971 _ZN2AG5Graph16update_attributeENS_4data3ptrINS_4NodeEEEj + 411
    133 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffa1656 _ZN2AG5Graph9value_refENS_11AttributeIDEPK15AGSwiftMetadataRh + 128
    134 AttributeGraph                      0x00007fff4ffb877a AGGraphGetValue + 291
    135 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d16cd4e $s7SwiftUI9GraphHostC17updatePreferencesSbyF + 39
    136 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cac8448 $s7SwiftUI9ViewGraphC13updateOutputs33_D63C4EB7F2B205694B6515509E76E98BLLyyF + 293
    137 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c7c72cb $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_AA010_UIHostingC0CyAA15ModifiedContentVyAA01_cj1_C0VAA0J17TableCellModifierVGG_Tg5Tm + 2021
    138 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5c6b9499 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFAA010_UIHostingC0CyAA15ModifiedContentVyAA03AnyC0VAA24NavigationColumnModifierVGG_Tg5 + 491
    139 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cc04546 $s7SwiftUI24NavigationBridge_PhoneTVC4push_4onto8animatedyAA0C18DestinationContentV_AA10PushTargetVSbtF011withUpdatedC3BarL_7performyyyc_tAA4ViewRzlFyycfU_ + 625
    140 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cc05c15 $s7SwiftUI24NavigationBridge_PhoneTVC4push_4onto8animatedyAA0C18DestinationContentV_AA10PushTargetVSbtF011withUpdatedC3BarL_7performyyyc_tAA4ViewRzlFyycfU_TA + 66
    141 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cb3575b $sIeg_ytIegr_TR + 12
    142 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cc0599c $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA + 17
    143 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5cc05f5a $sIeg_ytIegr_TRTA.34 + 9
    144 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d07620b $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtFyyXEfU_ + 2368
    145 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d06d9d8 $s7SwiftUI16ViewRendererHostPAAE6render8interval17updateDisplayListySd_SbtF + 345
    146 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d2cad1b $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyF + 296
    147 SwiftUI                             0x00007fff5d2cad61 $s7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewC14layoutSubviewsyyFTo + 21
    148 UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2561d2b1 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2962
    149 QuartzCore                          0x00007fff289e2d2e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 548
    150 QuartzCore                          0x00007fff289edebf _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 65
    151 QuartzCore                          0x00007fff28929c86 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 700
    152 QuartzCore                          0x00007fff28961853 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 699
    153 UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2508c831 _afterCACommitHandler + 105
    154 CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036bc67 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    155 CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2036648c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 541
    156 CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20366a3c __CFRunLoopRun + 1126
    157 CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203660f3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    158 GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2c995cd3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    159 UIKitCore                           0x00007fff25059f42 -[UIApplication _run] + 928
    160 UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2505eb5e UIApplicationMain + 101
    161 Cookbook                            0x000000010b239b7f main + 63
    162 dyld                                0x000000010ca96ee9 start_sim + 10
    163 ???                                 0x00000001166c84fe 0x0 + 4671177982
)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Users/vittalk/Documents/Vittal/Xcode/XCode_Versions/13.2/Xcode_13_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/vittalk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cookbook-dsisqbaepepfucghbmspweyxdwqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Users/vittalk/Documents/Vittal/Xcode/XCode_Versions/13.2/Xcode_13_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Users/vittalk/Documents/Vittal/Xcode/XCode_Versions/13.2/Xcode_13_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Users/vittalk/Documents/Vittal/Xcode/XCode_Versions/13.2/Xcode_13_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib:/Users/vittalk/Documents/Vittal/Xcode/XCode_Versions/13.2/Xcode_13_2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/vittalk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cookbook-dsisqbaepepfucghbmspweyxdwqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator:/Users/vittalk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cookbook-dsisqbaepepfucghbmspweyxdwqi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PackageFrameworks
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: IsFormatSampleRateAndChannelCountValid(format)'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
CoreSimulator 783.5 - Device: iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (473C9914-33AC-43B0-BA02-F18081906489) - Runtime: iOS 15.2 (19C51) - DeviceType: iPad Pro (9.7-inch)
```

Comment: I get similar processVolumeScalar  errors with audiokit when I use the iPod touch simulator.  Phone simulators and devices work ok.